# Postresql dynamic index creation for many tables

Tags: postgresql, index, query

How can I create an index in Postgres dynamically over many tables but always with different names.

Lets assume table x has a column y with all table names of hundreds tables which need to get an index on their z column type numeric. How can I run a loop which dynamically creates with the table names of column y of table x indexes on every table?

Comment: Obfuscating names with `x`, `y` and `z` doesn't really help in understanding the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL with a `do` statement that iterates over the tables in a schema:

```
do
$$
declare
 l_statement text;
 l_rec record;
begin
  for l_rec in select y 
               from x
  loop
    l_statement := format('create index on %I (z)', l_rec.y);
    execute l_statement;
  end loop;
end;
$$
```

Postgres will automatically generate a name for the new index.